# Trouble expanding a del operator expression

Tags: vector-analysis

So when messing with some PDE, I came across this expression:

$$\nabla \cdot [(\vec{u} \cdot\nabla)\vec{u}] \hspace{12mm}[1]$$

I then tried to find whether I can expand it by breaking it down component by component and then reassemble it (assuming $\vec{u}=(u1,u2,u3)$, where the us are functiosn of x,y,z) and then I got this after 5 hours of algebra

$$\vec{u}\cdot\nabla^2\vec{u}+\nabla \vec{u} \cdot \nabla\vec{u} \hspace{12mm}[2]$$

I also tried to naviely use the vector identity given in wikipedia

$$\nabla \cdot (\psi\vec{A})=\vec{A} \cdot \nabla\psi+\psi\nabla \cdot \vec{A}$$

to get something like this

$$\nabla(\vec{u}\cdot\nabla)\cdot \vec{u} + (\vec{u} \cdot \nabla)\nabla \cdot \vec{u} \hspace{12mm}[3]$$

But after expanding [3] component by component and compare with [1], I found it is off by the presence of the 2nd term of [3]

I also noticed that if the following is true

$$\nabla \cdot [(\vec{u} \cdot\nabla)\vec{u}]=\vec{u}\cdot\nabla^2\vec{u}+\nabla \vec{u} \cdot \nabla\vec{u}$$

then by what we know about vector calculus, the tensorial order of this expression should be 0

However I have trouble interpreting this

$$\nabla \vec{u} \cdot \nabla\vec{u}$$

If I treat the vector gradient as a 2nd order tensor (e.g. a matrix), then this is like matrix multiplication, but this will give me a tensorial order of 2 and not 0

It I treat it instead as some sort of norm squared, then I am at lost on how to compute it (What type of matrix norm would this be?)

So basically

> Q1. How to interpret this term?
>
> $$\nabla \vec{u} \cdot \nabla\vec{u}$$
>
> Q2. Why does
>
> $$(\vec{u} \cdot \nabla)\nabla \cdot \vec{u}$$
>
> have to vanish for [1] to be true. how to interpret this geometrically?

Comment: Re: your second question.  [1] is not an equation, so how can it be true or false?

Comment: I am trying to say is that if you expand [1] into xyz components and then compare this with $$\nabla (\vec{u}\cdot\nabla)\cdot \vec{u})+(\vec{u}\cdot\nabla)\nabla \cdot \vec{u}$$ after expanding also in xyz components they don't equal unless $$(\vec{u}\cdot\nabla)\nabla \cdot \vec{u}$$ is zero, which means the vector identity does not apply thus I am wondering is it because of a mistake, or is there a rationale to force $$(\vec{u}\cdot\nabla)\nabla \cdot \vec{u}$$ to go to zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, first you've done a lot of voodoo here.  Let's try to simplify this from first principles.

First, consider the $u \cdot \nabla u$ part--take as convention that $u \cdot \nabla u = (u \cdot \nabla) u$ for the rest of this post.

We can expand this by an identity to

$$u \cdot \nabla u = \frac{1}{2} \nabla u^2 - u \times (\nabla \times u)$$

Now we can take a divergence:

$$\nabla \cdot (u \cdot \nabla u) = \frac{1}{2} \nabla^2 u^2 - \nabla \cdot [u \times (\nabla \times u)]$$

That second term is going to be fun.  Let's expand it:

$$\nabla \cdot [u \times (\nabla \times u)] = (\nabla \times u)^2 + u \cdot [\nabla \times (\nabla \times u)]$$

That should get you an identity involving just derivatives of $u$ or $u^2$.

Now, regarding your two questions:  for (Q1), I don't even see how that question can be answered.  If you don't have any definition of what a gradient of a vector field is, then how can you justify the manipulation that got you to write it down?

For (Q2), when you directly expand $\nabla \cdot (u \cdot \nabla u)$ according to the product rule, you get at the least

$$\dot \nabla \cdot (\dot u \cdot \nabla u) + (u \cdot \nabla)(\nabla \cdot u)$$

where the dots denote that $\dot \nabla$ differentiates only $\dot u$.  So the term you're concerned about is definitely there; it's possible it cancels in some way, but I suspect that the $\nabla \cdot (\psi A)$ identity you tried to use doesn't hold when $\psi$ is a scalar differential operator instead of a scalar field.

Comment: I see...

For this term here
$$\dot \nabla \cdot (\dot u \cdot \nabla u)$$
can we expand it further or is this already fully expanded thus we cannot do anything about it?

Comment: Clarification on Q1: I recall that in uni during my second year the professor of multivariale calculus said you cannot take the grad of a vector field because the resulting object is a 2nd order tensor, which for xyz basis defined as taking the gradient of each of the vector components

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient#Gradient_of_a_vector

which is why I am wondering whether for the dot produce between the gradient of a vector field whether I am dealing with something like tensor contraction but I have no idea how to interpret that because I am not good at tensors

Comment: You can define $\nabla u$ as a higher-order tensor, yeah, but I just tried to avoid it here. - As far as $\dot \nabla \cdot (\dot u \cdot \nabla u)$, I did first try an approach based on expanding that term. I think that could be promising also.

Comment: $$\dot \nabla \cdot (\dot u \cdot\nabla u)+(u \cdot \nabla)(\nabla \cdot u)$$
$$=[\dot \nabla(\dot u \cdot\nabla)] u+[(u \cdot \dot \nabla)(\dot \nabla \cdot u)+(u \cdot \dot \nabla)(\nabla \cdot \dot u)]$$
$$=[\dot \nabla(\dot u \cdot\nabla)] u+[u \cdot (\dot \nabla(\dot \nabla \cdot u))+u \cdot (\dot \nabla(\nabla \cdot \dot u))]$$
$$=[\dot \nabla(\dot u \cdot\nabla)] u+u \cdot [(\dot \nabla(\dot \nabla \cdot u))+(\dot \nabla(\nabla \cdot \dot u))]$$

Comment: $$=[\nabla^2u+\nabla \times (\nabla \times u)] u?!+u \cdot [[(u \cdot \nabla)\nabla?!+u \times (\nabla \times \nabla ?!)]+[\nabla^2u+\nabla \times (\nabla \times u)]]$$

Ok I am stuck, got a lot of crazy terms...

Comment: Ok after 4 months I have tried again, and it seems I get different results depending on how the product rule is interpreted. for the 1st case using the convention:

$$\nabla\cdot\left[\left(u\cdot\nabla\right)u\right]$$
$$=\nabla\cdot\left[u\cdot\nabla u\right]$$
$$=\dot\nabla\cdot\left[\dot u\cdot\nabla u\right]+u\cdot \dot\nabla \cdot \dot\nabla u$$
$$=\dot\nabla\cdot\left[\left(\dot u\cdot\nabla\right)u\right]+u\cdot \nabla^2 u$$

Comment: This has the index notation as follows:
$$\partial_j\left[u_i\left(\partial_j u_i\right)\right]$$
$$=\left[\partial_ju_i\left(\partial_j u_i\right)\right]+u_i\left[\partial_j\left(\partial_j u_i\right)\right]$$
$$=\left[\partial_ju_i\left(\partial_j u_i\right)\right]+u_i\left(\partial_j^{(2)} u_i\right)$$

Comment: but treating it like this:
$$\nabla\cdot\left[\left(u\cdot\nabla\right)u\right]$$
$$=\dot\nabla\cdot\left[\dot{\left(u\cdot\nabla\right)}u\right]+\left(u\cdot \nabla\right)\left(\dot\nabla\cdot \dot u\right)$$
$$=\left[\dot\nabla\left(\dot u\cdot\nabla\right)\right]\cdot u+u\cdot \left[\dot\nabla \cdot \left(\dot\nabla u\right)\right]+\left[\left(u\cdot \nabla\right)\dot\nabla\right]\cdot \dot u+\ddot \nabla\cdot\left[\dot{\left(u\cdot \nabla\right)}\dot{\ddot u}\right]$$

Comment: You seem confused. $\dot \nabla \cdot \dot \nabla$ is nonsense.  $\ddot \nabla$ is also nonsense. Your results should be consistent with the notion that $\dot \nabla \cdot [(\dot u \cdot \nabla) u] = (\partial_i u^j) \partial_j u^i$.

Comment: Which has the index notation:
$$\partial_j\left[\left(u_i\partial_i\right)u_j\right]$$
$$=\left[\partial_j\left(u_i\partial _i\right)(u_j)\right]+\left[\left(u_i\partial_i\right)\left(\partial_ju_j\right)\right]$$
$$=\left[\left[\partial_j\left(u_i\partial_i\right)\right]u_j\right]+\left[u_i \partial_j\partial_i\right]u_j+\left[\left(u_i\partial_i\right)\partial_j\right]u_j+\left[\partial_j\left[\left(u_i\partial_i\right)u_j\right]\right]$$

So what have I done wrong?

Comment: EDIT: Just saw the recent comment that was 4s earlier of this. Do you mean we never differentiate a nabla and only ever differentiate a variable when using overdot notation?

Comment: Similarly in index notation, we never considered a $\partial$ as part of a product rule?

I seriously need clarification, because the associative property of $\partial$ in index notation makes it very hard to help me to compare my results with the overdot notation since in index notation you can freely change the brackets around as long the $\partial$ is not directly acting on a term

Comment: Partial derivatives are associative? Do you mean that they commute?

Comment: $$(\partial_i u^j) \partial_j u^i =\partial_i (u^j \partial_j) u^i ?$$

Comment: Technically, yes, but to me the left-hand side offers no substantive difference in meaning or advantage for computation. Conceptually, that's taking the derivative of a differential operator--it makes no sense.

Comment: So you mean e.g. to simplify this expression $$\partial_j (\partial_i u^j)$$ the correct way to do it is $$\partial_j (\partial_i u^j)= \partial_i \partial_ju^j$$ and not  $$\partial_j (\partial_i u^j)= \partial_j (\partial_i (u^j))+\partial_i (\partial_ju^j) $$ as if $\partial$ is a term in a product rule?

Comment: Yes. You have incorrectly applying the product rule. In your last expression, both those terms are equal, and you get a difference of a factor of 2 compared to the correct expression.

Comment: I see, I think I get it now: Index notation:
$$\partial_j[(u^i\partial_i)u^j]$$
$$=[\partial_j(u^i\partial_i)u^j]+[(u^i\partial_i)(\partial_ju^j)]$$
$$=[\partial_j(u^i\partial_i)u^j]+[u^i\partial_j(\partial_iu^j)]$$

Overdot:
$$\nabla\cdot[(u\cdot\nabla)u]$$
$$=\dot\nabla\cdot[(\dot u\cdot\nabla)u]+(u\cdot\nabla)(\nabla\cdot u)$$
Apply the $(a\cdot \nabla)b=a\cdot\nabla b$ convention:
$$=\dot\nabla\cdot[(\dot u\cdot\nabla)u]+u\cdot[\nabla(\nabla\cdot u)]$$
$$=\dot\nabla\cdot[(\dot u\cdot\nabla)u]+u\cdot[\nabla\cdot\dot\nabla \dot u]$$
$$=\dot\nabla\cdot[\dot u\cdot\nabla u]+u\cdot\nabla^2 u$$

Comment: where $\nabla^2$ is vector lapacian